# What doese implementation mean in the OOP context?

Tags: oop, interface, implementation

Trying to understand "`Program to an interface, not an implemenation`" you can find lots of examples like:

```
Dim pizza as PizzaInterface vs. Dim pizza as Pizzaclass
```

I would understand if they would write "Program to an interface, not an Class". I just dont know what implementation means. Is implementation the same as a concrete class in the OOP context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're somewhat correct. The meaning I'm getting is that you want to program to an Interface ( meaning there's an interface which defines methods ), but you shouldn't implement them... so no code inside. Not an abstract class to be clear!

To be clear, I never heard about some "code block" called "implementation"